# Aren’t photons the vector for energy input to earth?

Tags: earth-system

As such the fuel for earth’s Carbon cycle. 
Wouldn’t photons be the alleged “electromagnetic” mode of energy transfer into earth? 
Providing energy for the endothermic photosynthetic processes and heat for all and mass exposed to this energy modality. Mass can be gas, liquid or solid. In All instances converting thermic or light energy into increased molecular motion. 
What would be the vector for energy to be transferred out of earth atmosphere into the empty firmament.

Comment: please put some effort into making a more detailed question.

Comment: Maybe the question was posed to assist in research, so we are to provide the details?

Comment: Extremely unclear question. Vector for energy input? Energy is a scalar. The carbon cycle is driven by planetary-scale plate tectonics and surface rain runoff, not photons.

Comment: The term vetcor (something with magnitude and direction) is somewhat mislplaced here. They are best used in analysis. The best way to radiate energy off into space is by infrared wavelengths leaving earth (open sky, no greenhouse gases) or by reflecting incoming radiation directly, e.g. cloud layers, ice covers, anything that has a high (attention, here it comes) albedo. Is that what you're asking ?

Comment: Carbon dioxide +HOH+sunlight/chlorophyll ➡️Free oxygen + carbohydrates(sugars)/hydrocarbons(oil)

Comment: + Nitrogen ➡️ Amino acids➡️Proteins.    ➡️ Alcohols, organic acids, ketones, aldehydes.

Comment: @Jorge you need to focus on one single question,as it is now after your edit it is way too broad.please take a look here https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tour to see how to ask a question here on our site.

Comment: While the language in this question is obscure, I think the question itself is fairly clear, and comes down to: How does heat leave Earth? As such, it's a dupe of https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9728/how-does-earths-heat-escape-to-space

Answer (score 0):

Photons do not emit energy but rather, carry stored kinetic energy that has the potential to give or TAKE AWAY heat so, to answer your question, they ARE an energy vector but would think they are not the fuel for the Carbon Cycle since they get scattered by particles and water vapour....which leads me to think they are part of the cocktail, but not the fuel in itself. Here is an excellent visual and summarized source for interactions of radiation with the atmosphere > https://www.nrcan.gc.ca/maps-tools-publications/satellite-imagery-air-photos/remote-sensing-tutorials/introduction/interactions-atmosphere/14635

I believe you have asked an excellent question and look forward to reading the subsequent responses.

Comment: I think the question might be more about the energy light provides plants during photosynthesis, so they can convert carbon dioxide & water into sugar & oxygen.

Comment: Found this to add to the debate > key on the properties of photons what they can and can't do, in particular > "-They can have interactions with other particles such as electrons, such as the Compton effect.
-They can be destroyed or created by many natural processes, for instance when radiation is absorbed or emitted." https://www.zmescience.com/science/what-is-photon-definition-04322/ Does this affect your comment above ^ ?

Comment: Energy can’t be created or destroyed, it can only be transformed. Photons travel at 300,000 Km/sec. E=mc2.